# Cannot reach a temp table using Java SQL Statement object passed as a Map Value

Tags: java, sql-server, temp-tables

My code currently works something similar to this

```
public void foo (Statement st, String sqlStr, String tempTableName) {
String aString = foo(tempTableName);



boolean result = st.execute(aString); // creates temp table

// Now do something else in another method
writeToTT(st, tempTableName);

}

public void writeToTT(Statement st, String tempTableName) {
// Final String name
String finalSqlWithTempTableName = foo(tempTableName);

st.execute(finalSqlWithTempTableName);
}
```

The above works fine. However, when I pass the `Statement` object as part of a `HashMap` it fails inside the `writeToTT` method

```
public void foo (Statement st, String sqlStr, String tempTableName) {
String aString = foo(tempTableName);

st.exectue(aString); // Creates temp table

// Now do something else in another method but pass it within a map
Map<String,Object> mapObj = new HashMap<>();
mapObj.put("statement",st);

writeToTT(mapObj, tempTableName);

}

public void writeToTT(Map<String,Object> mapObj, String tempTableName) {
// Final String name
String finalSqlWithTempTableName = foo(tempTableName);
Statement st = (Statement)mapObj.get("statement");
st.execute(finalSqlWithTempTableName); // Fails here saying that tempTableName object doesn't exist.

}
```

I used a debugger to check the identity Hash Code using System.identityHashCode(obj) - and both cases (inside and outside the method frame stack) the hash codes are the same. It's indeed referring to the same object using the reference value passed in `paramMap`.

I am just trying to understand whether this is because how it's being passed as a new object reference with `HashMap` or is it because the actual statement object doesn't have a valid `hashCode` override?

My assumption/understanding is that the temp table location in memory and the `Statement` object's access to that memory location changes as soon as I pass it via `HashMap` even though the object `hashCode` remains the same within `writeToTT` method. But may be I am mistaken?

Comment: What does the method foo do using the tempTableName?

Comment: what RDBMS are you suing? session temp table  is visible only for the current session that creates it.

Comment: @PeterHe          Thanks. I’m using MS SQLSERVER 2016 SP2. I’m using plain SQL, and the foo method creates. SQL with temp table name and addition a temp index etc. As I mentioned, it works only if not passed within a HashMap.

Comment: You can check whether  finalSqlWithTempTableName  has the same temp table name as before the call to writeToTT

Comment: @PeterHe         finalSqlWithTempTable doesn't have any issue with the name it's the same name as a String. It's the actual `Statement` object which loses access to temp table in the memory.

Comment: Looks to me a different connection is used. Temp table only visible to the connection that creates it.

Comment: @PeterHe         please check the post regarding the object references. they have the same object reference for connection and the actual `Statement` object - there is no new connection initiated